# Amcl localization accurate, but slightly offset from lidar data

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have what looks like a very good localization of the robot to the map. But when overlaid with the current lidar scan data, the localization is just a little offset, but with high confidence. See attachment. What would cause that? How do I interpret that?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363487/amcl-localization-accurate,-but-slightly-offset-from-lidar-data/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2020-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think an incorrect static transform somewhere is causing this. Make sure that your laser_link to base_link tf is correct.

Also does this continue happening when you are moving? AMCL does not update when stationary (unless you explicitly call [/request_nomotion_update](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl)) and therefore, if there is motion after the last update before stopping sometimes the laser scan will be offset from the static map.

But in all cases the offset is the same, then I think a static transform might be off.

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1